# No se pueden alcanzar las urls de localhost proporcionadas cuando se ejecutan las imágenes docker

Tags: docker, jupyter, networking, bokeh, port

Cuando intento ejecutar un contenedor docker que inicia jupyter con el comando os dentro de un script o una imagen docker neo4J tengo un problema de red. Tengo ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED o ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

## ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

Cuando ejecuto jupyter notebook parece que todo funciona bien en la terminal:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix seriousgame:latest
Run bokeh server? ([y]/n) 
n
Run jupyter server? ([y]/n) 
y
[I 10:14:20.667 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 2021-12-13 10:14:20.942 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-12-13 10:14:20.942 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-12-13 10:14:20.945 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-12-13 10:14:20.945 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/serious-game
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6 is running at:
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 10:14:20.950 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 10:14:20.950 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
```

Pero ninguno de los enlaces funciona ... Creo que es porque no se puede acceder a jupyter desde la imagen Docker. Porque cuando lo hice desde la máquina donde hay jupyter puedo acceder al cuaderno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los requisitos está jupyterlab, no sé si es suficiente:

```
bash-5.1$ cat requirements.txt 
bokeh
jupyterlab
matplotlib
networkx
pandas
scipy
```

El Dockerfile seguro que descarga los requisitos:

```
bash-5.1$ cat Dockerfile 
#############################################################################################################
#
#   Creation du container
#
##############################################################################################################

FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04
MAINTAINER me

EXPOSE 5006
EXPOSE 8888

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV WD=/home/serious-game/
WORKDIR ${WD}


# Add git and ssh
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install git ssh pkg-config python3-pip python3-opencv

# Dépendances python
COPY requirements.txt  /requirements.txt
RUN cd / && \
     python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN ls
COPY start.py /start.py
CMD ["/start.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

Así que parece ser un error de red porque cuando intenté mover el cuaderno desde el localhost del contenedor sigo teniendo el error "This site can't be reached" ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED.

```
inpt = input("Run jupyter server? ([y]/n) \n")
if inpt.upper() in ["YES", "Y", ""]:
    os.system("jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root")
    return
```

Aquí está el resultado completo:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -p 8888:8888 seriousgame:latest
Run bokeh server? ([y]/n) 
n
Run jupyter server? ([y]/n) 

[I 09:45:21.148 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 2021-12-16 09:45:21.416 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-12-16 09:45:21.416 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-12-16 09:45:21.418 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-12-16 09:45:21.419 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/serious-game
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6 is running at:
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 09:45:21.424 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 09:45:21.424 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
```

## ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Curiosamente, tengo un problema de red similar con cuando se ejecuta una imagen Docker neo4j no puedo llegar a la imagen docker neo4j que trató de ejecutar:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run neo4j
^[[1;5C2021-12-16 09:55:17.973+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-12-16 09:55:18.312+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{d3a250fb} (d3a250fb-24b6-400d-82d2-5ff00740060f)
2021-12-16 09:55:19.163+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.4.1 ========
2021-12-16 09:55:20.406+0000 INFO  Initializing system graph model for component 'security-users' with version -1 and status UNINITIALIZED
2021-12-16 09:55:20.410+0000 INFO  Setting up initial user from defaults: neo4j
2021-12-16 09:55:20.411+0000 INFO  Creating new user 'neo4j' (passwordChangeRequired=true, suspended=false)
2021-12-16 09:55:20.422+0000 INFO  Setting version for 'security-users' to 3
2021-12-16 09:55:20.425+0000 INFO  After initialization of system graph model component 'security-users' have version 3 and status CURRENT
2021-12-16 09:55:20.429+0000 INFO  Performing postInitialization step for component 'security-users' with version 3 and status CURRENT
2021-12-16 09:55:20.739+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2021-12-16 09:55:21.298+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-12-16 09:55:21.300+0000 INFO  id: 6A9C435FEE30E82F3EF0611B5D98AB44CCF970739EA66D61896B3C801FA2A2B7
2021-12-16 09:55:21.300+0000 INFO  name: system
2021-12-16 09:55:21.301+0000 INFO  creationDate: 2021-12-16T09:55:19.614Z
2021-12-16 09:55:21.301+0000 INFO  Started.
```

Y obtengo ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image]

Probaré una webapp de Django y añadiré los resultados.

Tal vez hay un problema en la dirección IP?

```
bash-5.1$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:79:cc:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:6e:e0:f0:32:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.178/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
       valid_lft 168207sec preferred_lft 168207sec
    inet6 fe80::41c7:dafd:7a6:4f44/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:20:72:95:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:20ff:fe72:9551/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.254.99/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7be4:d988:98c1:8551/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: veth6503edf@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether c2:c7:b8:5f:39:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c0c7:b8ff:fe5f:396f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## Así que no puedo llegar a las urls hasta ahora, otras ideas?

### ¿El volumen no es el seguro?

El compañero que me dejó esta imagen me dice que el directorio de trabajo debe estar montado como volumen.

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -p 8888:8888 -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /home/ac/Documents/Work/serious-game seriousgame:latest
```

Pero obtengo el mismo error ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

Y parece que sirve para el directorio correcto, ¿no?

```
[I 2021-12-13 10:14:20.945 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/serious-game
```

### Con el puerto de contenedores visible desde el exterior

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix seriousgame:latest
```

Pero aqui esta lo que me contesta el navigador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Problemas en IP addr?

```
bash-5.1$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:79:cc:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:6e:e0:f0:32:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.178/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
       valid_lft 168207sec preferred_lft 168207sec
    inet6 fe80::41c7:dafd:7a6:4f44/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:20:72:95:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:20ff:fe72:9551/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.254.99/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7be4:d988:98c1:8551/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: veth6503edf@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether c2:c7:b8:5f:39:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c0c7:b8ff:fe5f:396f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Voy a centrarme en lo último que has preguntado, pues de lo anterior no tengo claro qué está pasando. Respecto a lo de lanzar jupyter, ten en cuenta que el servidor Jupyter se queda escuchando en el contenedor, y que las IPs que te dice al final para acceder  son las del contenedor. Estas no están accesibles "desde fuera". Pero si añades al `docker run` la opción `-p 8888:8888` entonces el puerto 8888 del contenedor será visible desde fuera. Eso significa que puedes ya conectar desde un navegador que se ejecute en ubuntu si usas la url `http://localhost:8888`

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia ! Probé tu comando pero me contesta el navigador que la url `might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`

Comment: Es que no tengo del todo claro tu setup. Por un lado tienes un servidor Linux que es en el que ejecutas docker. Cuando usas la opción `-p 8888:8888` al lanzar el contenedor, eso hace que el servidor Jupyter quede accessible en el puerto 8888 del servidor linux. Por otro lado tienes un navegador con el que quieres conectar ¿ese navegador está también en el servidor linux? Si es así, conectarlo a `localhost:8888` debería funcionar. Pero si el navegador está en otra máquina (Windows por ejemplo) tienes que usar en cambio la IP del linux en la URL

Comment: La ip de la máquina linux la puedes averiguar poniendo `ip addr` en el shell. Lo que te salga ha de ser una IP en la misma subred que la IP de la máquina que ejecuta el navegador. Si no es así es que probablemente hay de por medio un router NAT, lo cual complicaría aún más la cosa (pero todo tiene solución)

Comment: Sí, lancé el comando Docker en la terminal de un Fedora y traté de acceder a Google Chrome desde esta misma máquina, @abulafia He añadido la salida del comando ip addr

Comment: Propongo validar tu configuración de red mediante una imagen popular de Jupyter  : https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/base-notebook/dockerfile  que se expone en 8888 mas info en :https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-base-notebook

Comment: Tbn recomiendo utilizar docker compose para esto casos,  otra cosa que no veo es la creación de red típica [overlay|bridge]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitaba añadir `--ip 0.0.0.0` al comando jupyter notebook, o servirá en el localhost del contenedor, que no es alcanzable desde mi host.

Es una buena cosa tambien crear un archivo docker-compose para ordenar las cosas, construir/ejecutar el contenedor fácilmente, con algo como :

```yaml
versión: "3.8"

servicios:
  app:
    image: seriousgame:latest
    construir: .
    entorno:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
    volúmenes:
      - .:/home/serious-game/
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

Una buena práctica es usar también Makefiles, con make como ENTRYPOINT, entonces uno sólo tiene que ejecutar su objetivo Makefile usando :

```sh
docker-compose run app {serve_bokeh,serve_jupiter,sh}
```